# ReactJS API ( Get specific properties )

Tags: reactjs, api

I have an Endpoint which returns an array of objects, and i need to display some of those properties into a Table ( Each object has more than 100 properties, i just need 5 or 6 ).. my question is, What's the best way to achieve this? i've been using React-Table to display some info, but this endpoint is a bit more complex.. (Objects are not valid as a React child)

Comment: I'm no expert on how react-table works but it's either case of mapping api objects to your required structure or providing  those 5-6 columns to react-table (if it has functionality of filtering only properties specified in it's columns). However, you should consider providing more details, because from what you've presented so far  it seems to be trivial problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Example:

```js
const data = [
  {prop1: 11, prop2: 12, prop3: 13, prop4: 14},
  {prop1: 21, prop2: 22, prop3: 23, prop4: 24},
  {prop1: 31, prop2: 32, prop3: 33, prop4: 34}
];

// Assuming you are only interested in prop1 and prop2
const filteredResult = data.map(item => (
  {prop1: item.prop1, prop2: item.prop2}
));

console.log(filteredResult);
```

Comment: Hello @klugjo, this seems to be working! the data i receive from the API is set on state,  there is any way i can make data = this.state?

Comment: Sure just do `const filteredResult = this.state.map(...)` instead

Comment: I've tried that, just found the problem, i was not setting a default value to state! Everything working now!

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using lodash, it has a method called **[pick](https://lodash.com/docs#pick)** that does what you want when coupled with map:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
const object = [{ 'a': 1, 'b': '2', 'c': 3 }, { 'a': 2, 'b': '3', 'c': 4 }];

const result = object.map((item) => 
  _.pick(item, ['a', 'c'])
);

Console output of result: [{ 'a': 1, 'c': 3 }, {'a': 2, 'c': 4 }]
```

Or, if you just need the values and not the keys, you could try underscore's [pluck](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) method